# Why does .aspx is not responsing after some time when the session is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .aspx page with a few textboxes and a submit button. Once the submit button is clicked the value is show on textbox.

That works fine. if doing it right away but if i click the button after 22 mins or so the page errors out.  Here i did not use any session..Please help me. i am using .net4.0 version

error is : Runtime Error Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. –  nanabidh n 6 mins ago

–  nanabidh n 5 mins ago

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: And can we maybe see some code?

Comment: Can i upload image here.

Comment: Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: Please ***edit your question*** to include error text *and* source code that re-creates the problem. Additionally please include what server, VS and .NET versions you are using.

Comment: My web config is :  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="600"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="500"/>
    </authentication>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="40000"/>

Comment: my simple code behind code is :                                    protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            TextBox1.Text = "test";
        }

Answer (score 0):

22-23 minutes is really a lot of time. So I suggest you to:

1. Enable showing errors in web.config - more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
2. Attach debbuger to your site and check on which part of code it hangs
3. If 2 is not possible, look into the code which is invoked and/or add logging in it

Comment: I think  22 or 23 mins is very small time for  fill up a big registration page . User may take more then one hour for fill up it.
you can see this link http://www.nanabidh.com/registration/IAmATutor.aspx?RE=RE
Thanks your answer. i am trying your suggestion.

Comment: If i solved above testing  problem then also i can solved my actual issue. Thanks

Comment: hello Garath, in local server it has no  problem. Problem has live server.

Comment: i have use : <configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                    mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="500"
                redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration> now its redirect at InternalError.htm page after 23 mins

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a cookie.  Check out which version of security you are using in your web.config file.  If you are using forms authentication then it automatically places a session timeout in the session cookie.  The session cookie resets anytime you perform any type of request from the server and the server sends a response to the client.

The client will timeout usually in 15 to 20 minutes.  You can constantly reset this using Ajax calls without the need for a page refresh.  But if you stop performing requests and the server doesn't send a response to the client, the client will only have the latest session cookie and will timeout after the server or session timeout you had set up whether you are aware of it or not.

Comment: i have use : <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="500"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: Just look up forms authenication cookie in a browser or this link for best results. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443